# Inequality $a+b+c > abc$, prove $a^2+b^2+c^2 > abc$

Tags: inequality

Given, $$a+b+c > abc$$

Prove $$a^2+b^2+c^2 > abc$$

I tried to square the first one but it wouldn't work.

Comment: it doesn't say they are integers does it?   - if we square both sides, we get nearer the desired result, but we need to justify the existence of combinations of a,b,c variously multiplied - and they don't have to be positive

Comment: Not enough context and/or efforts. Moreover, the inequality does not hold if we are free to take $a,b,c$ as complex numbers, for instance as the roots of $x^3-3x^2+8x-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ac$$ holds,  since it is equivalent with $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0.$$ Also $$ab+bc+ac\geq\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}.$$ Previous inequality holds, since it is equivalent with $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\geq abc(a+b+c),$$
which is equivalent with $$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\geq 0$$ for $x=bc$, $y=ac$, $z=ab$.

Finally, $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ac\geq\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}\geq\sqrt{3}abc>abc$$

Comment: Where did the 3 come from in the second step.

Comment: $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\geq abc(a+b+c)$ holds, then add $2abc(a+b+c)$ on both sides in order to get $(ab+bc+ac)^2\geq 3abc(a+b+c)$ and square it.

Comment: You may wish to add some justification for negative numbers also.  Looks good for non-negatives...